# Regex for digits from 0 to 16 digits Only in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, digits

I have a text field that is the user choose to enter data in it, it must be digits and must be less than or equal to 16 digits (Not more than that).

I have regular expression for digits,

```
ValidationExpression="^\d{10}$"
```

which is be exactly 10 digits. But how to modify it for my scenario?

I am embarrassed by such a simple question, but I got confused. If it is a duplicate question or somebody asked similar question, please let me know.

**Note:** I need the regex for `ASP.net`

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a good tutorial.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

```
^\d{0,16}$
```

Note, that in .NET, `\d` can also match **any** Unicode character that represents a digit ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter)). If you really just want the ASCII digits, use

```
^[0-9]{0,16}$
```

(Since I am not sure how you would set `RegexOptions` if that is possible at all in your case.)

Comment: I think you meant to say "locale" rather than "culture".

Comment: @MarkReed I was pretty sure it was called "culture" in .NET... I'll look it up

Comment: @MarkReed first thing I could find: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172470(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: yeah, you're right. odd that they chose a different term from the standard one - "culture" has a lot of overtones that don't necessarily map to locale settings.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @MarkReed however, it doesn't seem that the culture is what actually makes the difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter ... it's always Unicode unless you use a specific `RegexOption`. I should edit that.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot guys. Sorry for this basic question and thanks for the generous answer.

Comment: @AbdulAziz no problem. Although many people would probably say you could have easily googled that, your question was asked very politely with a perfect amount of detail and your attempt. That is a lot more than many other questions here (at least with a regex tag). So I would gladly answer this ;). If you are planning to do more with regexes in the future (or anyway, since it's always useful), please do read through the whole tutorial I linked. It explains everything very nicely.

Comment: @AbdulAziz - If I may suggest, either Trim() the string before you validate it against this regex. Or modify the regex to allow for leading and trailing whitespaces. Something like: ^\s*\d{0,16}\s*$

Answer (score 2):

The curly-brace quantifier is `{`*min*`,`*max*`}`, so `{0,16}` will do for your case.

Comment: You should stick with `{0,16}`; the `{,max}` syntax is far from universal.  .NET doesn't seem to support it, anyway.